# Devise Sign In Issue: Rails 3.2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Long question, but thought I'd try to be thorough. :)

I've followed this tutorial "How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address":

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

So I'm clearly not an expert at this! I've also seen a few similar posts here, but nothing has worked for me yet.

Essentially I want to set up my app so that users sign up with username and password, not an email address. Not concerned with ever getting a user's email address or any kind of password recovery. Just need simple UN and Password authentication. My sign up works just fine. I can create new users all day long. However, after logging out of a user, I can't log back in. I get the "Invalid username or password" message.

Here's what I'm working with:

In the console I get the following 401 authentication error:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-24 17:52:15 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HIFrqmz+LFMTzeULLDedlonWmtUGU0bniseLwcxtv64=", "user"=>{"username"=>"bobbiebear", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

My User Model user.rb is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :login
  #attr_accessible :email

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end


### This is the correct method you override with the code above
### def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
### end

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

end
```

And the view (HAML) in question:

```
%h2 Sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
  = f.input :username, :autofocus => true
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  = f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn-primary'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

And also

```
#devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
  config.confirmation_keys = [ :login ]
  config.unlock_keys = [ :login ]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.sign_out_via = Rails.env.test? ? :get : :delete
end
```

And just in case this provides any insight, my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130824210400) do

  create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], :name => "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  add_index "roles", ["name"], :name => "index_roles_on_name"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email"
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username", :unique => true

  create_table "users_roles", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], :name => "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"

end
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT AND SOLUTION**

So I reverted back to before I went through the above mentioned tutorial.

Here's how I fixed the problem. First, I decided to include the authentication_key variable which is commented out in devise.rb in the User model (:validatable, :authentication_keys => [:username])

I changed it from :email to :username. I also made :username attr_accessible. Then finally I added

```
  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end
```

So for the User model now I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

end
```

Then I updated the views so that :email was not required and added :username fields...

SIGNUP

```
%h2 Sign up
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = display_base_errors resource
  = f.input :name, :autofocus => true
  -#= f.input :email, :required => true
  = f.input :username, :required => true
  = f.input :password, :required => true
  = f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true
  = f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn-primary'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

And Sign In

```
%h2 Sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
  -#= f.input :email, :autofocus => true
  = f.input :username, :autofocus => true
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  = f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn-primary'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got it working already, but here it is.

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username %>


#config/initializers/devise.rb

config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

to

config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

And then change the forms to handle username instead of email.

This has worked for me, so I hope it helps! (with Rails 4 and devise 3)

Comment: I did thank you! I also added   `def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end` to my User class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the virtual attribute `login` is really required here, you could have achieved this by using just `:username`.

Anyway, I think the problem lies in your view.  You need to change your input field to be `:login` and not `:username` like follows:

```
%h2 Sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f|
  = f.input :login, :autofocus => true
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
  = f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn-primary'
= render "devise/shared/links"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still seeing the same results when switching the view as you suggest. You inspired me though. I reverted back to before I did the tutorial and I think I've fixed the problem...